# How to prove this criteria of differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, derivatives

Let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $a\in \operatorname{int}(I)$. Suppose that there is $L\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim \frac{f(y_n)-f(x_n)}{ y_n-x_n}=L$$ for all sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $I$ with $x_n < a < y_n$ and $\lim x_n =\lim y_n = a$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable in $a$ and $f'(a)=L$.

I have proved a similar result, but that assumes $f$ differentiable, something like the converse of the criteria above. Some hint for that one?

Comment: You might be able to find something here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184578/prove-that-f-is-differentiable?rq=1

Comment: Right there we can find an aswer. Thanks a lot!